# How to get value of public key for hashing (PyKCS11)

Tags: cryptography, smartcard, hashlib

While using PyKCS11, I extracted a public key from a smartcard. Now, I need to hash that key with sha256. However, the public key object contains a lot of values:

```
CKA_ALWAYS_SENSITIVE: True
CKA_CLASS: CKO_PUBLIC_KEY
CKA_DECRYPT: False
CKA_DERIVE: False
CKA_ENCRYPT: False
(...)
CKA_KEY_TYPE: CKK_RSA
CKA_MODIFIABLE: False
CKA_MODULUS: (200, 163, 157, 146, 3, (...))
```

To hash the key (using hashlib) it is required only one of the attributes (it doesn't accept iterables).

What attribute should I use? I was thinking about CK_VALUE or CK_MODULUS, but the documentation on PyKCS11 doesn't make it very clear which one is correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you need to hash depends on what you require.

Generally the modulus is hashed, not the encoding of the entire key. Hashing the modulus will result in the same value for both the public and private key so that you can identify both as being from the same pair. The result or the leftmost bytes of the result are often used as *key check value* or KCV.

The modulus should be unique for each key pair. If it isn't your random number generator is likely broken or not well seeded (it can't hurt to check this if you generate multiple keys). So a hash over the modulus will uniquely identify your public key, even if the exponent wasn't hashed.

Comment: Well, in this scenario I want to exchange messages with a server. I'm going to send the hashed public key of my smartcard to that server and I'll keep the private key to myself (it stays in the smartcard). With this in mind, I really need a way to uniquely identify each key, so, according to what you just wrote, maybe I shouldn't hash the modulus (since it produces te same result in both private and public keys).

Plus, I found out there's a function on PyKCS11, session.digest() which lets me hash the key with sha256, so I don't need to use hashlib. But the problem is still there.

Comment: Are you afraid that you mistakenly send the private key? What's the point of sending a hash of the public key to the server? You cannot verify or decrypt with the hash of a public key - just sending the public key itself makes a whole lot more sense - preferably in some trusted fashion of course.

Comment: The hashed public key (digest) serves as an ID of the user (the owner of the smartcard)

Comment: Well, as I said, since the modulus identifies the public key then there is nothing wrong by using that. If you want to include the public exponent - usually simply 0x010001 - then be my guest, but 1) you have to decide on an encoding and 2) it won't add any additional identifying information.